# Advanced custom field for each on range

Tags: php, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to echo out an unordered list when i set my Range slider to a number. In example when i put the range slider in ACF to 4 i want my page to echo out:

- Flywheel 1
- Flywheel 2
- Flywheel 3
- Flywheel 4

Is this possible?

--> Edit:

I cant get this to work:

```
<?php 
$flywheelnumber = get_field('flywheels');
if( $flywheelnumber ) {
    echo '<form class="checklist-list">';
        echo '<ul class="slides">';
        foreach($flywheelnumber) {
            echo '<li>';
                echo ( $numbers );
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</form>'  
}
?>
```

Comment: Sure ... get the value `4`, and then write a simple `for` loop. Where is the actual _problem_ with that?

Comment: @CBroe, i cant get it to work:

<?php 
$flywheelnumber = get_field('flywheels');
if( $flywheelnumber ) {
 echo '<form class="checklist-list">';
  echo '<ul class="slides">';
  foreach($flywheelnumber) {
   echo '<li>';
    echo ( $numbers );
   echo '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
 echo '</form>' 
}
?>

Comment: `foreach($flywheelnumber)` - that makes little sense. For one, foreach needs an "as" argument at least, and then looping over a singular numeric value, is also rather pointless. Use a `for` loop, https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: @CBroe

<?php
$flywheelnumber = get_field( 'flywheels' );
if ( $flywheelnumber ) {
    echo '<form class="checklist-list">';
    echo '<ul>';
    for ( $x = 1; $x <= count( $flywheelnumber ); $x ++ ) {
        echo '<li>' . $x . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</form>';
}
?>

Im getting a error in the FOR loop

Comment: Saying that you are getting "a error", is really not all that helpful. Quote error messages verbatim.

Comment: @CBroe

Error message:

Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /Users/rms01/Local Sites/nfs-no-limits-checklist/app/public/wp-content/themes/tmj/template-car.php on line 20

Line 20:

    for ( $x = 1; $x <= count( $flywheelnumber ); $x ++ ) {